# upload local path to msql

Tags: java, php, html, xml

I'm trying to create a sql database that stores among as one of the fields the files local directory path (on a local server).

some of these files are .ai and .cdr files which are quite large. I have seen some code that uploads/moves to another folder, but since these files are so large i don't want to double up on files on the server. and I don't want the editable files moved from their original directory.

is there anyway to use the input="file" browse function to display the file local path and then save the data in the sql database

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

se it before your code  customize your upload limit

```
<?php
echo ini_get('upload-max-filesize'),'<br />'
,ini_get('post-max-size'),'<br />';
?>
ini_set('upload-max-filesize', '10M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '10M')
```

Comment: will this still give a local path for files over 10M?

Comment: ini_set('memory_limit', '256M'); chage the value 256 than try again